# Why does older Android device outperform newer device on RenderScript application?

Tags: android, performance, renderscript

I'm testing image processing app on several devices. The app has two versions: strictly sequential one, and RenderScript optimized one. Older device performs worse on sequential, but better on RenderScript solution than a newer device (specs below). Only difference I've noticed is that older device had no other apps running while testing, while newer device had multiple (chat and social media).

Older device:

- released in 2017
- **Chipset**: HiSilicon Kirin 960 (16 nm)
- **CPU**: Octa-core (4x2.4 GHz Cortex-A73 & 4x1.8 GHz Cortex-A53)
- **GPU**: Mali-G71 MP8
- **RAM**: 4GB
- **Android version**: tested on both 8 and 9

Newer device:

- released in 2019
- **Chipset**: Exynos 9820 Octa (8 nm)
- **CPU**: Octa-core (2x2.73 GHz Mongoose M4 & 2x2.31 GHz Cortex-A75 & 4x1.95 GHz Cortex-A55)
- **GPU**: Mali-G76 MP12
- **RAM**: 8GB
- **Android version**: 9

I understand that RenderScript has underlying logic how best to paralelize given the available hardware, but also current circumstances can affect that (e.g. low battery level - worse performance).

Does anyone know why older device with somewhat weaker CPU works better than the new one?

Comment: There is insufficient information to determine why. Any answers will just be guesses without the necessary measurements as to what the devices are actually doing so far as software loaded and running, device condition and state, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm aware there may be more needed information. Can you suggest something specific I can add to the question details?

Comment: I suggest you do some research into this area to see what other people are doing, what kinds of measurements they are taking, etc. Frankly this question isn't really a good fit because it is so open ended and vague. It depends not only on the device hardware and the device state and the mix of apps in the device but also on the RenderScript functionality and the image processing app functionality.

Comment: Thank you @Richard Chambers, will do. I was just wondering if anyone faced something similar, so they can give a suggestion in what direction to look.

Comment: As an example as to variability, see this answer that mentions different GPUs having different drivers which can affect RenderScript https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151628/1466970